# Python basic string split method behaviour

Tags: python, string

I have the following function which I used to find the length of the places in a binary number where zeros are encapsulated by ones:

```
def solution(N):
# write your code in Python 2.7
# convert to binary
binary = bin(N)[2:] # results prefixed with '0b'
# special case of no zeros
if '0' not in str(binary):
    print('No binary gap in %s'% str(binary))
    return 0
# special case of all zeros after first 1
if '1' not in str(binary)[1:]:
    print('No binary gap in %s'% str(binary))
    return 0
# special case of N == 1 = 01
if N == 1:
    print('No binary gap in %s'% str(binary))
    return 0

bgaps = []
sbin = str(binary)
print(sbin)
spbin = sbin.split('1')
print(spbin)
for i in spbin:
    if i == '': continue
    bgaps.append(len(i))

return max(bgaps)

for N in [6,328,147,15,2,483,647]:
    print(solution(N)
```

The results show that string split doesn't always return a `''` where the delimiter used to be. The happens e.g. for `101001000` where the split returns

```
['', '0', '00', '000']
```

instead of

```
['', '0','', '00', '', '000']
```

I suspect that this has to do with a special meaning of '01' but the delimiter is '1'. Any thoughts on why this split behaves this way?

Comment: this is not 2.7

Comment: `split` throws away the delimiter: `"a,b,c".split(',') == ["a", "b", "c"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Added exception if last element is a 1.

How about replacing the "1" with "11" adding an empty space between.

```
sbin = '10100100'

if sbin[-1] == "1":
    print(sbin.replace("1","11").split("1")[1:-1]) # remove first and last
else:
    print(sbin.replace("1","11").split("1")[1:]) # remove first
```

prints

```
['', '0', '', '00', '', '000']
```

Comment: An interesting solution :-)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to misunderstand how `str.split` works. Since `1` is at the start of the string, the empty string appears on the left side of the split at the start character; `str.split` puts this into consdiration:

```
>>> '1'.split('1')
['', '']
```

Looks like you don't want to *split*.

You probably want something of the sort:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sbin = '101001000'
>>> ['' if k=='1' else ''.join(g)  for k, g in groupby(sbin)]
['', '0', '', '00', '', '000']
```

Comment: I was going to post a solution with `groupby` too, but it appears as if the OP is doing homework, in which case using something like `gropuby` would probably be considered cheating. Maybe provide a hand-rolled solution as well?

Comment: @ChristianDean I added that since they've shown some effort at working the larger part 'alone' :)

Comment: @ Moses Koledoye Appreciate the clarification. This question is not "homework" just learning python via the "Codility"  and GeeksforGeeks websites.

Answer (score 2):

As @ForceBru mentioned, split removes the delimiter which is the same behavior in a lot of languages. You probably want to approach this differently (perhaps using a combination of split + replace or something similar to count the gaps).

Hope that provides some insight.